# nativescript angular RTL plugin not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm building an Arabic blog so I need my app to be RTL direction I have searched and I found that plugin from nativescript that's `nativescript-rtl/ui`

## The problem is not working right the tabs still LTR and Tabs animations still LTR as well the Labels text still LTR?!

**My code:** 
app.module.ts

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
import * as rtl from '@nativescript-rtl/ui'

registerElement(
    "RGridLayout",
    () => rtl.GridLayout
);
registerElement(
    "RWrapLayout",
    () => rtl.WrapLayout
);
registerElement(
    "RAbsoluteLayout",
    () => rtl.AbsoluteLayout
);
registerElement(
    "RDockLayout",
    () => rtl.DockLayout
);
registerElement(
    "RStackLayout",
    () => rtl.StackLayout
);
```

home.component.html

```xml
<RGridLayout class="page page-content">
    <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <Label [nsRouterLink]="['../item', item.id]" [text]="item.name" class="list-group-item"></Label>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</RGridLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide a github example so we can check as i just used LTR plugin today with there example and everything worked fine.

Comment: Label would automatically go right if text is arabic (any language that is RTL), moreover the plugin doesn't add any changes to the core Label component. So if you have issues, please share a Playground Sample where issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I'm using the tabs-template-ng and just installed the `tns plugin for RTL` then changed the `StackLayout` to `RStackLayout` after register them on `app module` nothing change